# Calculating cumulative averages (How do i do it?)

Tags: python, list, function, append

I have three functions, one to calculate lab average, one for weighted scores, and one for program average. These functions calculate the scores of a particular student that the user selects. (For ex. Will calculate lab avg. for only Ablao not other students)

```
Ablao 3 74 96 72 88 71 80 83 77 90 88 95 71 76 94 80 74 98 77 
Anderson 3 76 92 98 95 92 76 93 97 85 76 85 93 82 88 75 84 92 77 
Aspinwall 1 86 74 78 97 86 94 73 95 74 91 75 94 83 99 83 78 88 96 
Bacon 4 72 95 81 80 89 88 100 87 87 81 79 77 75 83 87 96 72 95
```

There is information for 60 students in the file. The first number after the name stands for the grade of the student. 1=Freshman 2=Sophomore etc.

I need to create a new function that will use my existing functions to calculate the averages of ALL the students collectively, and of students for each grade and then average those averages, find the max and min.

The code i have written so far for this function does not work and I do not know how to begin approaching the problem.

```
with open(FileName, 'r') as f:
    line = f.readlines()

student_status=(float(line.split()[1]))

def make_lists_of_status():
    if (student_status==1):
        Freshman.append(student_scores)
    elif (student_status==2):
        Sophomores.append(student_scores)
    elif (student_status==3):
        Juniors.append(student_scores)
    elif (student_status==4):
        Seniors.append(student_scores)
```

Expected output should be like

```
    This  option is for viewing statistics sorted by the year of student.
    Please select one of the following options: 
    a for ALL YEARS
    b for FRESHMAN
    c for SOPHMORES
    d for JUNIORS
    e for SENIORS

Enter your choice here: e

For Seniors:
High/Low/Mean of all Weighted Scores:  89.53999999999999 /   81.60000000000001 / 86.15736842105264
High/Low/Mean of all Lab Averages:  89.6 / 80.2 / 86.21052631578948
High/Low/Mean of all Program Averages:  94.33333333333333 / 77.0 / 86.78947368421052
```

Comment: Could you show us your code for the other three functions? Do you mean that you want to calculate the average of all the student's results?

Comment: @MoonCheezes the functions work for one student at a time, which they are supposed to but i need a new function that will calculate for all the students and sort the scores by grade

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a dictionary.

```
students = {}

with open("inCSV.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        data = line.rstrip().split(" ")

        student_name = data[0]
        student_grade = data[1]
        student_data = [int(x) for x in data[2:]]
        student_avg = sum(student_data[2:])/float(len(student_data[2:]))

        # Set the students name to a tuple of student's grade and average
        students[student_name] = (student_grade, student_avg)

# Sort the students by their averages. (Descending order)
# Add reverse=True to have it in ascending order
print sorted(students.keys(), key=lambda x: students[x][1])
```

**EDIT**

It can still be done in a similar fashion.

```
students = {}

def weighted_scores(x):
    return x

with open("inCSV.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        data = line.rstrip().split(" ")

        student_name = data[0]
        student_grade = data[1]
        student_data = [int(x) for x in data[2:]]

        student_program_avg = sum(student_data[2:])/float(len(student_data[2:]))
        # Edit this part to your code
        student_weighted_scores = weighted_scores(data[2:])
        student_lab_averages = lab_average(data[2:])

        students[student_name] = (student_grade,
                                  student_weighted_scores,
                                  student_lab_averages,
                                  student_program_avg)
print students

def get_level(x):
    ret_dict = {}
    for k, v in students:
        if v[0] == x:
            ret_dict[k] = v


def choose(x):
    people = get_level(x)
    overall = []

    for s in range(1, 4):
        # Get grades of either weighted scores, lab averages or just average.
        # Sort grades in descending order
        grades = sorted(people.keys(), key=lambda x: people[x][s])

        highest = grades[0]
        lowest = grades[-1]
        mean = sum(grades[2:])/float(len(grades[2:])

        overall.append((highest, lowest, mean))

    # overall[0] => weighted scores
    # overall[1] => lab averages
    # overall[2] => program average
    # overall[x][0] => highest of x
    # overall[x][1] => lowest of x
    # overall[x][2] => mean of x

    print "For %i level:" % (x)
    print "High/Low/Mean of Weighted Scores: %i / %i / %i" % (overall[0][0], overall[0][1], overall[0][2])
    print "High/Low/Mean of Lab Averages: %i / %i / %i" % (overall[1][0], overall[1][1], overall[1][2])
    print "High/Low/Mean of Weighted Scores: %i / %i / %i" % (overall[2][0], overall[2][1], overall[2][2])

# Let's say you picked seniors:
choose(4)
```

Comment: Ive been altering this code but it is not working for me. What is the comments you have under overall.append ? @MoonCheesez

Comment: Those comments are just describing to you how to index the overall list. `x` is either weighted scores, lab averages or the program average.

Comment: Ok so where the 0's are do i replace that with 0 for highest, -1 for lowest ? @MoonCheesez

Comment: @Rachel, sorry had an error, when indexing `overall` it should be 0 for highest, 1 for lowest and 2 for mean. When indexing the grades, as it is sorted from highest to lowest. The first element is the highest, the last element is the lowest (index -1).

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
scores_student = {}
scores_grade   = [[],[],[],[]]
scores_all     = []
with open("students.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        # Parse the line
        toks   = line.split()
        name   = toks[0]
        grade  = int(toks[1])
        scores = [float(tok) for tok in toks[2:]]
        # Save scores both per student, in that student's grade, and total
        scores_student[(name,grade)] = scores
        scores_grade[grade-1] += scores
        scores_all += scores

# Print individual student info
print "Students"
for name,grade in sorted(scores_student):
    score = scores_student[(name,grade)]
    print "%-10s %d mean %4.1f max %3d min %3d" % (name, grade, sum(score)/len(score), max(score), min(score))
print
print "Summary"
for grade, score in enumerate(scores_grade):
    if len(score) > 0:
        print "grade %d mean %4.1f max %3d min %3d" % (grade+1, sum(score)/len(score), max(score), min(score))
print "all     mean %4.1f max %3d min %3d" % (sum(scores_all)/len(scores_all), max(scores_all), min(scores_all))
```

Comment: I will edit my question to include the expected output @amaurea